# Проект Node express + Vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

У меня есть два проекта в VS. Один - это API Node express, второй  - это Vue SPA. Вопрос: как запустить их одновременно так, чтобы протестировать взаимодействие API и клиента. Если я просто запускаю их через солюшн, то один из них всегда не запускается, даже если они на разных портах (например 1337, 1991). CDN мне также не походит.

Comment: Что конкретно не может?

Comment: Запускаю через зеленый треугольник в VS (делает npm run build, но я не уверен). В консоли пишет либо Debugger listening -> Debugger attached -> GET \ 304 -> GET main.css 304 -> Debugger attached если я первым запускаю Express либо " App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:1337/
  - Network: http://10.47.209.241:1337/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build." если первым запускаю Vue.

Comment: `const router = new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: HomeVue
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            component: LoginVue
        },
        {
            path: '/map',
            component: MapVue
        },
        {
            path: '/test',
            component: TestVue
        }

    ]
})


new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    router
}).$mount('#app');` Vue код

Comment: `app.set('port', 8080);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});`
Express

Comment: @HelloThere, Рекомендую посмотреть npm-run-all (если `&` в npm-скрипте не помогает), и использовать Cypress для тестирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В *package.json*:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev:back": "node pathToYourExpressServerIndex.js --watch",
  "dev:front": "vue-cli-service serve --port 3000",
  "dev": "npm run dev:back & npm run dev:front",
  "build": "vue-cli-service build"
},
```

Запуск через `$ npm run dev`
Для запуска этой команды через debug-интерфейс VS Code (клавишей F5 / зеленой кнопкой запуска), его нужно сконфигурировать через `.vscode/launch.json`.

Так веб-приложение будет запущено на localhost:3000, a экспресс-сервер (судя по комментарию к вопросу), у тебя забиндится на порт 8080, прописанный хардкодом.

---

**p.s.**: Предполагается наличие *vue-cli*.

Comment: Да именно это и сработало, почему не работает зелёный треугольник в VS не знаю.

Comment: @HelloThere, Его надо настраивать, но хз как... Откровенно говоря, средствами отладки VS Code я никогда не пользовался - по привычке юзаю отладчик браузера и расширение Vue devtools))